# How do I change the selected color with a select option tag instead of a list?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, interpolation

I've got a Vue component with images that change color when I click a list item with the color.

```
    <div class="product__machine-info__colors">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(color, index) in machine.content[0].machine_colors" :key="color.color_slug" v-if="color.inStock" v-on:click="selectColor(index)"
          v-bind:class="{ active: (color.color_slug === selectedColor.color_slug)}">
          <img v-bind:src="color.color_dash">
        </li>
      </ul>
    <div>
```

This works fine and changes the images I need to change.
Now I want the same effect but the list needs to be a select box with options.

I've got this so far but not sure how to make it work.

```
        <div class="product__machine-info__mobile__inner--color select-style">
          <select name="machineColorWay">
            <option v-for="(color, index) in machine.content[0].machine_colors" :key="color.color_slug" v-if="color.inStock" v-on:select="selectColor(index)"
              v-bind:class="{ active: (color.color_slug === selectedColor.color_slug)}" v-bind:value="selectColor">
              {{ color.color_slug }}
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

Any help would be appriciated.

This is the component that needs to be changed onchange of the select option (the Carousel one)

```
<div class="product__carousel">
    <Carousel showIcon v-if="selectedColor" :machineColor="selectedColor" />
    <!-- Image carousel gets loaded in -->
    <div class="product__machine-info__mobile">
      <div class="product__machine-info__mobile__inner">
        <div class="product__machine-info__mobile__inner--color select-style">
          <select v-on:change="selectedColor(index)">
            <option v-for="color in machine.content[0].machine_colors" :key="color.color_slug" :value="color.color_slug">
              {{ color.color_slug }} 
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a select, you no longer need your method `selectColor`. You can use a `v-model`. I renamed `color` in the loop to `currentColor` to keep a better overview, since `color` has been defined in `data` according to your provided code.

```
    <div class="product__machine-info__mobile__inner--color select-style">
      <select name="machineColorWay" v-model="color">
        <option v-for="currentColor in machine.content[0].machine_colors" :key="currentColor.color_slug" v-if="currentColor.inStock"
          v-bind:class="{ active: (currentColor.color_slug === color.color_slug)}" v-bind:value="currentColor">
          {{ currentColor.color_slug }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: This worked for me! The other awnser probably too if I tried a bit longer :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something when a user selects a color. One way to achieve this is the following.

Define an on-change handler on the `select` field.

```
<select name="machineColorWay" v-on:change="selectColor">
```

Now, in the handler, you could get the selected value like this

```
selectColor(event) {
    let color = event.target.value;
    // now do what you wanna do with the value. Here the value
    // is what you pass using the `v-bind:value="selectColor"`
}
```

Another way would be using a `v-model` and `watcher`.

First, bind the `select` to a data model.

```
<select name="machineColorWay" v-model="selectedColor">
```

Define the `selectedColor` in the `data` property.

```
data() {
    return {
        selectedColor: null
    }
}
```

Now using a watcher on the `selectedColor` you could call your `selectColor` function with the changed `selectedColor` value.

```
    watch: {
        // whenever color changes, this function will run
        color: function (newColor, oldColor) {
           console.log(newColor, oldColor);
        }
    }
```

Here is a working JSFiddle:

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      colors: [{
          slug: 'white',
          name: 'white'
        },
        {
          slug: 'green',
          name: 'green'
        },
        {
          slug: 'blue',
          name: 'blue'
        },
      ],
      color: 'white'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectColor(event) {
      let color = event.target.value;
      this.color = color;
      console.log(color);
    }
  }
}
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <template>
  <select placeholder="Select" v-on:change="selectColor">
    <option v-for="item in colors" :key="item.slug" :value="item.name">
    {{ item.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
  
  <p>Selected Color: {{ color }}</p>
</template>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working for me. Too bad I don't have anyone here to code check me, so I have to find out myself. Sorry but could you give me a real time example? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Only thing I can't figure out now is how to make the image carousel I made change color. It's a standalone component inside the component with the selectbox. I will change my question and show you what I mean.